# Why is this returning true?

Tags: c++

I started C++ a few hours ago and have been trying to do a simple LinkedList implementation in it to get myself familiar with it, however, I'm stumped as to why this method `hasNext()` keeps returning true.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct LinkedNode {
public:
    int data;

    LinkedNode(int d = 0) {
        data = d;
    }

    void setNext(LinkedNode * linked_node) {
        next = linked_node;
    }

    LinkedNode * getNext() {
        return next;    
    }

    bool hasNext() {
        return (next != nullptr);
    }

private:
    LinkedNode * next;
};

int main() {
    LinkedNode * linked_list = new LinkedNode(2);
    (*linked_list).setNext(new LinkedNode(10));
    if (linked_list->getNext()->hasNext()) {
        cout << "true";
    }
    else {
        cout << "false";
    }
}
```

This outputs "true", but when I try to access the data since it is supposedly "true" I get the `Segmentation fault` error, (going to guess it's being raised since I'm trying to get a value that doesn't exist), from `linked_list->getNext()->getNext()->data;` Can somebody explain why?

Comment: In C++, primitives (such as pointers) are filled with garbage unless you initialise them.

Comment: You never initialize `next` properly, what do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initializing next. By default allocating memory just changes a data structure storing information about what memory block is allocated. It does not change the content of this memory block. So you can consider the next pointer be of random data. And since random data is different than null pointer hasNext returns true but when you access the data it is very likely that the random data is interpreted as a pointer into some memory that either does not exist or your application does not has the right to access too. Therefore the result in segmentation / page fault.

To verify this truth just do not initialize data as well, create some nodes and read the data (or even the next pointer). This way you see the randomness which is basically just left overs of content the memory block once hold before it was freed.

PS: Memory blocks are freed and dynamically spliced and combined based on algorithms you can learn. Check out malloc and some other implementations and see the Wikipedia about memory allocation.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of `LinkedNode` does not initialise the `next` member.

That means it is uninitialised.   It is not set to zero by default.   In fact, accessing its value (before initialising it, or assigning a value to it) gives undefined behaviour.

Set `next` to be `nullptr` within the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You must initialize the value of `next` to `nullptr`. By default, the value is undefined (garbage).

Check out [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
LinkedNode(int d = 0) 
    : data( d )
    , next( nullptr )
{

}
```

Or simply assign the values directly in the constructor body:

```
LinkedNode(int d = 0) 
{
    data = d;
    next = nullptr;
}
```